# What is the show-identification tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I've noticed recently that some edits have been made to start adding in [show-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/show-identification) to some questions asking "help me identify a tv show about *x*".

There are currently only [24 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/show-identification) using this tag.

Should we continue using it, or should we discontinue using it and use [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) for all "help me identify" questions regardless of the media?

If we should be using [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) exclusively for these questions, should the two be synonymized?

Comment: And here I was, thinking it was a demand to show my identification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We certainly shouldn't use [show-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/show-identification). Definitely use the standard [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), and I'm inclined to say [tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series) as well. We don't generally include medium, but I think story ID is broad enough to warrant it.

Comment: Yes, that was IIRC what we originally decided when this was debated in the past. Can't seem to find a link

Comment: Given this, should the [tag:show-identification] tag be made a synonym of [tag:story-identification]?

Comment: @Beofett Sure, why not.